# MySQL Datetime - Gap identification

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am designing a MySQL database that will contain minute by minute data collected from a remote source.

I plan for the data table to hold a datetime field and as such I might have 3 months of data each row representing the values at each minute.

How can I identify gaps in the data easily? Should I even be using datetime?

I will be using PHP5 for the application itself.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: if you are building a logging application then consider using TIMESTAMP data type

Comment: In what situations would there be gaps? Lack of connection to remote source?

Comment: Yes, where the connection to the remote service is unavailable.

Comment: (or my cron to check the data source isn't running for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

I'd give each row a unique sequential reference (1,2,3...) then do a self join on the table

```
...from mytable t1 join mytable t2 where (t1.ref+1)=t2.ref
```

Depending on how you store the dates, you can subtract them (one way or another) and determine if there is a gap. Wrap the whole thing in a query that extracts the rows where there is a gap.

You might want to consider storing the dates as seconds from a particular start date.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the gaps is an interesting problem. The best approach will depend on the size of the gap, but here is another way to tackle it, and one which might be better if the gaps are reasonably large compared to the number of records you have.

Use a MySQL aggregation function in a query to count the number of records for a set of buckets. The buckets need to be similar in size to the kinds of gaps you are interested in. Assuming you're interested in gaps approximating a day or so, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS(my_timestamp), COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(my_timestamp)
```

This will return an association between days and timestamp counts. I'd do the rest in a language like Perl or Java (or even R, see later) where I can process the data.

The technique I'd use would be a test of the difference between the observed frequency (the count) and the expected frequency, which will be the total number of records, divided by day range. The expected frequency for each day would be something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) / 
        ((SELECT TO_DAYS(MAX(my_timestamp)) FROM my_table) - 
         (SELECT TO_DAYS(MIN(my_timestamp)) FROM my_table) + 1)
```

Now, for each bucket (remembering that in the first result, completely missing days will just be not returned, not returned as a count of zero -- you need to treat them as if they are zero, you can use a statistical test, the chi square test, to estimate the probability of this being chance (for details, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test). The calculation is, basically ((expected - observed)^2 / expected). This is an estimate of the likelihood of deviation.

If you need to work out which buckets are low in samples, set a reasonable threshold on this calculated value, and look for buckets where the value exceeds the threshold. It may take a little experimentation to devise an appropriate value, but this is a sound way of determining gaps.

Comment: Why R? Well, it has some very good built-in stuff for statistical calculations like the chi square tests